# Matrix calculations in second order polynomial approximation

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I am looking at second order polynomial approximation, specifically at this [link](https://smt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_src_docs/surrogate_models/qp.html). 
However, I am stuck in the one dimensional case: I do not think I can calculate the following:

$$ X^{T}*X^{-1}*X^{T}*y$$

Suppose I have as sample points $x = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]$, then from what I understood in the link my matrix should become:
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 &  1 \\
    1 & 2  & 4 \\
    1 & 3  & 9 \\
    1 & 4  & 16 \\
    1 & 5  & 25
\end{bmatrix}
Ignoring the columns $x_1*x_2, \cdots x_{nx-1}x_{nx}$ because I do not have more dimensions. Suppose I calculate $X^{-1}$ with Matlab pinv command,
still I cannot do $X^T * X^{-1}$. Is this a problem with the single dimension and it gets solved with $d > 1$?

Comment: @Leo I though it was $nt$ x $(1 + 3*d)$, isn't that so? Also because I have been reading this wikipedia article which talks about the same thing in my mind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression

Comment: @Leo If X is $n$ by $m$, $n \neq m$, then $X^{-1}$ is actually $m$ by $n$, check it with the pinv command

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo on the site,

$$
\boldsymbol{\beta} = \color{red}{(} {\bf X}^T {\bf X}\color{red}{)^{-1}} {\bf X}^{T} {\bf y}
$$

If you use `y = [0.0, 1.0, 1.5, 0.5, 1.0]`, you should get `beta = [-0.9, 1.22142857, -0.17857143]`

[image]

Comment: What is the form of the  X matrix in your example?

Comment: @qcc101 the same you have in your post